# Mac Mini 2011 and DP video output is unstable - blanks multiple times in 10 minutes

Tags: display, mac-mini, displayport

I brought last year a Mac Mini 2011 (the base model with Intel 3000 HD). Yesterday I brought a Dell U2713H. I now run with two displays connected and the other displays have been reliable before adding the new monitor.

1) The monitor alone with the mac mini works 100% OK no mater the cable i use.

2) To my surprise, when i connect a second 1080p or lower res monitor to the mac mini the Dell monitor goes black for a few seconds out of the blue! Then after say a second or two the image returns. It feels like the cable loses the connection for a moment.

The issue appears ONLY when i connect the Dell monitor with the display port to mini dp cable and ONLY when the resolution is 1440p. If I set the resolution on the Dell monitor to 1080p or 2048x1152, everything works OK.

---

Tell me your opinion guys, the Mac Mini, the Monitor or the cable is to blame?

Tests also prove that the monitor is OK under windows 7 via bootcamp. It also works OK on a windows PC. It's an OSX compatibility issue (10.8).

---

This guy got exactly the same problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4546769?start=0&tstart=0

and: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19479698.aspx

Comment: Is the blanking a one time event when you connect things or is this something that happens several times a day (or better happens on a schedule or responding to events you have determined)?

Comment: Thank you for the response! It blanks at random times very frequently, say once every few seconds. Usually happens when I move windows or fullscreen a video.

Comment: Also, is important to note that this thing happens VERY frequently if i click on the second display.

Comment: I've edited some of these details into the question. Please proof my changes and add anything else needed to complete the story. These comments can be deleted once the question has all the facts in the right order.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to install windows on the mac to see if it's a software thing.

Comment: It works fine on bootcamp... It must be a compatibility issue... Any idea what software can i try to fix that?

Comment: I would certainly file a bug with Apple - http://bugreporter.apple.com since they might just need to update the drivers or fix a configuration file. Hopefully someone has seen something similar and can offer advice so you can run the resolution you prefer.